# InfoPath 2010 How to avoid validation when a section is hidden?

Tags: forms, list, sharepoint, controls, infopath

I am trying to design an info path form that links to a share point list.
I have a "extra" section on the form which is only visible if a check box value = true.

The problem is some of the fields on the "extra" section is mandatory. So when the check box value = false, the section is hidden and I cannot fill in the fields. But when I try to submit the form I get an error message to say mandatory fields must be completed. But I do not want to complete those fields.. as the section is to be kept hidden.

Any suggestion on how to get this working would be very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add the required field checkbox instead create a validation rule that checks if your value is true and the hidden field is empty then send a required error.

This way you can submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

put a sample value on that field like "none" then when the section is checked, set a rule that will clear that field.